# How do i go down a line in v-combobox - vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using `v-combobox` to view a list of `v-chip` and it looks like this:

[image]

I want to add a line break between each chips.

Here is my code:

```html
<v-combobox
  :append-icon="false"
  style="
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
  "
  :search-input.sync="search"
  v-model="chips"
  :items="items"
  chips
  clearable
  color="#0D47A1"
  label="Your actions..."
  multiple
  readonly="true" :key="chips.name">

  <template
    v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, select, selectedSetups }"
    style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji'">
    <v-chip
      class="list-group-item"
      v-bind="attrs"
      :input-value="selectedSetups"
      color
      label
      close
      @click="select"
      @click:close="RemoveRequirement(item)"
      outlined>
      <span>{{ item.category }}</span>&nbsp;
      <v-divider
        class="mx-4"
        color="black"
        inset
        vertical
        v-show="item.value.toString() != ''"></v-divider>
      <span>{{ item.value.toString() }}</span>
    </v-chip>
  </template>
</v-combobox>
```

Any idea on how to achieve that please?

Comment: would be awesome if you provide a codesandbox to i can help you instead of creating your example by myself.
for you its just copy paste for now.

Comment: what do you mean? where do you want me to paste my code? thanks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io create a example same to yours in the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this using css, but this also shifts the dropdown down with every selection. That is probably not desired. Try it out and see for yourself:

```css
div[role=combobox] .v-select__slot .v-select__selections {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```